# TYPO3 Section Menu Get Image and Typolink

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am trying to make a custom section menu of content elements that contains the first image in the element. How do I get the image?

Also what am I doing wrong  with my typolink below?

This is what I have got so far:

```
tt_content.menu.20.101 < tt_content.menu.20.3
tt_content.menu.20.101 {
  1.NO {
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    wrapItemAndSub = <div>|</div>
    stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
    stdWrap.cObject {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = header
        10.typolink.parameter.field = uid
        20 = TEXT
        20.field = rowDescription
        20.wrap = <h6>|</h6>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the associated files.
depending on your CE definitions the fieldname may vary (`files`,`images`, `media`)

you may use something like:

```
renderObj.30 = FILES
renderObj.30 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="pic">|</div>
    references {
        table = tt_content
        #uid.data = uid
        fieldName = image
    }
    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj {
        file {
            import.data = file:current:uid
            treatIdAsReference = 1
            width = 150c
            height = 150c
        }
        altText.data = file:current:alternative
        titleText.data = file:current:title
        #params = class="menu-img"
        stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
    }
    maxItems = 1
}
```

---

For your link (a second question would be appropiate as a different topic):
an integer value for `.typolink.parameter` will link to that page. you provide an integer, but it's the uid of the content element.

You need a link to a section:

```
typolink {
    section.cObject = TEXT
    section.cObject.field = uid
    section.cObject.wrap = c|
}
```

The wrap depends on the rendering of anchors in your templates. I assume `c` as it is the default.

Comment: You're awesome thanks, the image works perfectly. The typolink doesn't seem to do anything... should I make a new question?

Comment: Made a new question for the typolink part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233417/typolink-inside-section-menu-coa