# Typolink inside section menu COA

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a custom section menu where I need a specific part of the menu item to be linked instead of the whole thing.

At the moment the typolink part doesn't do anything:

```
tt_content.menu.20.101 < tt_content.menu.20.3
tt_content.menu.20.101 {
  1.NO {
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 0
    stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
    stdWrap.cObject {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {    
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = header
        10.typolink {
          section.cObject = TEXT
          section.cObject.field = uid
          section.cObject.wrap = c|
        }
        20 = TEXT
        20.field = rowDescription
        20.wrap = <h6>|</h6>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the output I want from the example above would be something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/elementpage/#c1234">Element Header</a>Element Description etc..</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @insertusernamehere Have updated with an example output.

Comment: are you sure about your url? I would expect either `"#c1234"` or `"mysite.com/currentpage/#c1234"` your links always go to the root page

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I have updated the output example. Need the link to the page/element. Same as what you'd get from the default section menu except on only on part of the COA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Typolink/Index.html?highlight=typolink) you will find two possibilies:

1. insert the complete anchor (with hash) into parameter
2. use `.section` in combination with a page id for parameter (assuming the anchor is on another page)

that gives two solutions:

```
typolink {
    paramter.cObject = TEXT
    paramter.cObject {
        field = uid
        wrap = #c|
    }
}
```

or

```
typolink {
    parameter.field = pid
    section.cObject = TEXT
    section.cObject.field = uid
    section.cObject.wrap = c|
}
```